# (Swift) How to implement a Page Control through paging single views?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, pagecontrol

I want to implement a **page control** in my project so that every view can be accessed through swiping *left or right*. Every example I have looked at is to do with images, not **views**. I've been studying [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift) and its of course images again. My application is a *single view application*. I'm not really sure what code snippets to give you so far, I don't think I do because I haven't done anything on this yet. If you need specifics, please comment and ask me, i'll be here all day.

Please help me!
**Thanks.**

Comment: UIPageViewController

Answer (score 0):

The same idea should apply in the tutorial you cited. They're adding `UIImageView` to a `UIScrollView`. So in your case, instead of `UIImageView` just use `UIView`. Also you can think of the `pageImages` array as a data source about your views. For example, instead of an array of `UIImage` you can just have an array of some model object that helps you configure your view. However, keep in mind that the implementation in the tutorial for your case won't scale if you plan to have a lot of UIViews. That's because you want to effectively reuse views that aren't showing. **When it gets to that point, you're better off implementing a UITableView that scrolls horizontally.**

Comment: Yeah i understand, thanks for the comment, I'm pretty new to programming so I don't understand how to do half of what you said. Are you saying all I do is change the image views to UIViews?

Comment: Yes. Since you're new to iOS programming, I highly recommend looking into understanding Model-View-Controller and UITableView. It will help you grasp the design patterns used for making components similar to what you're working on now.

Comment: I already know a lot about UITableViews, just not really what I need to do here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIPageViewController` for paging effect. Check out [this](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) tutorial. It is written in obj-c but who cares. It will give you idea about using `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Yer I've looked at this before, i've never worked with Obj-c before, i know i have to just understand what methods and stuff but I know I will stuff something up, I just can't follow that..